# parametrizing browserifiy bundle contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle, browserify

I've got a project built (bundled) with browserify. It supports some functionalities for different locales (different languages). Currently, all locales are loaded using `commonJS` `require`s in a row:

`exports.a = require('./a')
exports.b = require('./b')
exports.c = require('./c')
...`

but, as you may expect, the bundle get very big and a typical user uses only one locale at a time. The case is to parametrize the bundle somehow. The question is: **how to do it** the best way.

The brute-force I thought of is to provide an input parameter with list of locales, generate a node module which will require only chosen locales and run browserify against it. But it's a nasty brute force, looking for something else.

The are some transforms, such as *globify*, which allow to bungle chosen filepath wildcards. But I'm not sure whether I can use it in this case.

There is also [*partitioning*](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#partitioning) in browserify: *factor-bundle* and *partition-bundle*. I was analysing partition bundle in this case: to create a map of locales that could be loaded in the browser runtime. But haven't tried it.

I'd appreciate hints on what is a good solution in this case.